# Getting Facebook Profile ID in FBGraphUser

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API in an iOS app. The [FBGraphUser](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphUser/) protocol contains a property called **user's ID**, but it's not that same as the **Profile ID** in Facebook.

When I type the user's id after facebook.com/xxxxxxx .. it displays Page not Found.

The idea is: how to get the Profile ID instead of user's ID using GraphAPI?

Comment: Try `https://graph.facebok.com/{user_id}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be related to the changes to the Facebook API and introduction of the Graph API 2.0. [Facebook has said](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/f8/):

> To protect people's information, we will begin to issue app-scoped
>   user IDs instead of original user IDs for people who first log in to
>   your app using the new Graph API.

It basically means you won't be getting the user's real User ID, but instead a localised ID that is unique for that user in your application.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for!
But now, how could I get the friends' count for the user of my application?!

Comment: You now need to ask for the `user_friends` permission too, and then you can access the friends list. However, Facebook has said it will only return friends who also use the app.